# Searching by Finder Tags not working in Spotlight on macOS High Sierra

Tags: spotlight, search, finder-tag

I started using Finder Tags very extensively a while ago. However, I noticed this strange bug (at least on my macOS High Sierra): **Searching for tags by writing**

```
tag:<name_of_tag>
```

**is not working for me in Spotlight**.

I can successfully write `<name_of_tag>` into Finder search window, and it will both recognize it as tag and show me the relevant files. Therefore, it looks like a bug specific to Spotlight, as searching for tags is supposed to work system-wide.

Is there any workaround or fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the internet a little bit, I found a [recent post in Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31579937#31579937) explaining the reason for bug. In non-english versions of macOS (at least German and Slovak), searching by

```
tag:<name_of_tag>
```

query does not work. **Replacing the `tag` keyword by `kMDItemUserTags` fixes the problem** and properly shows relevant files even from Spotlight:

```
kMDItemUserTags:<name_of_tag>
```